# Laravel 4.2 upload images not working when install to web hosting

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-4, iis-8

It worked on xampp(php artisan serve).
i using:

```
            $file =Input::file('img');

            $archivo = value(function() use ($file){
                $filename = str_random(34) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                return strtolower($filename);
            });


            $destinationPath = 'public/uploads/';
            // Move file to generated folder
            $check = $file->move($destinationPath, $archivo);
```

---

when I install to web hosting with virtual directory (cut /public uri and rewrite index.php)

It not working.

```
        $file =Input::file('img');
            //$fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $archivo = value(function() use ($file){
                $filename = str_random(34) . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                return strtolower($filename);
            });
            //var_dump($archivo);

            $destinationPath = 'uploads/';
            // Move file to generated folder
            $check = $file->move($destinationPath, $archivo);
```

Files uploaded to web server(folder /uploads) but it defectives and it cann't use,When I download with filezilla call **Error:  Critical file transfer error**

**windows server 6.2,IIS 8.0**

Answer (score 0):

This works fine.

```
    if(Input::Hasfile('image')){
        $files = Input::file('image');
        $filename = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$files->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $ext = explode('.',$filename);
        $ext = strtolower($ext[count($ext)-1]);
        $upload_success = $files->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    }else{
        $filename = Input::get('upload_image','');
    }
```